# Verbose GC Logging in relation to max memory

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I have some memory related issues in my application.
Question is how is PSYoungGen and PSOldGen related to maximum memory of Java application?

My application has 3072MB set.
And following is a heap stats from verbose GC logs:

```
Heap
PSYoungGen      total 165184K, used 110272K [0xfffffd7ec8010000, 0xfffffd7ed49b0000, 0xfffffd7fc8010000)
 eden space 153344K, 71% used [0xfffffd7ec8010000,0xfffffd7ecebc0040,0xfffffd7ed15d0000)
 from space 11840K, 0% used [0xfffffd7ed15d0000,0xfffffd7ed15d0000,0xfffffd7ed2160000)
 to   space 26560K, 0% used [0xfffffd7ed2fc0000,0xfffffd7ed2fc0000,0xfffffd7ed49b0000)
PSOldGen        total 2175552K, used 1820513K [0xfffffd7bc8010000, 0xfffffd7c4cca0000, 0xfffffd7ec8010000)
 object space 2175552K, 83% used [0xfffffd7bc8010000,0xfffffd7c371e8598,0xfffffd7c4cca0000)
PSPermGen       total 131072K, used 52898K [0xfffffd7bc0010000, 0xfffffd7bc8010000, 0xfffffd7bc8010000)
 object space 131072K, 40% used [0xfffffd7bc0010000,0xfffffd7bc33b8898,0xfffffd7bc8010000)
```

How are totals related to my 3GB max heap space? When added its still less then my 3GB (2340736)

Comment: what kind of options do you use? Xmx? Xms?

Comment: if Xms < Xmx java can dynamically change current heap size

Comment: so if I set Xms to 3072 then OldGen and YoungGen will sum up to my 3GB?

Comment: i believe it is true